# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am a begginer to python.
I create a graph as below to view on tkinter window.
But It gave me some error.

Error :

```
figure.set_canvas(self)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'
```

---

This is my coding part:

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x**2+b*x+c

xlist = np.linspace(-10, 10, num = 1000)
##print(xlist)

a = 5
b = 1
c = 4
ylist = f(xlist, a, b, c)

plt.figure(num = 0, dpi = 120)

ax = plt.plot(xlist, ylist, label = 'f(x)')
print(type(ax))

plt.title('Plotting Example')
plt.xlabel('Distance / ft')
plt.ylabel('Height / ft')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
# plt.show()
# __________________________________________________________________
my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.geometry('1000x820+50+50')
my_w.title('data view on tk graph')

wrapper1 = tk.LabelFrame(my_w)
wrapper2 = tk.LabelFrame(my_w)
wrapper1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=5, pady=5)
wrapper2.pack(fill="both", padx=5, pady=5)


canvas = tk.Canvas(wrapper1, bg="#595656", height=200)

canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
# __________________________________________________________________


plot1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(ax, canvas)
plot1.draw()
plot1.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=5, pady=5)

ctrl_frame = tk.Frame(wrapper2, bg='green', height=100)
ctrl_frame.pack(fill="both")

tk.Button(ctrl_frame, text='View', width=15, command=lambda:None).place(relx=0.9, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.E)

my_w.mainloop()
```

## __________________________________________________________________

Please help me to set the graph on tkinter window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


# ax = sns.set()
def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x ** 2 + b * x + c


xlist = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)

a = 5
b = 1
c = 4

ylist = f(xlist, a, b, c)

figure = plt.figure(figsize = (5,4), num = 0, dpi = 120)
figure.add_subplot(111).plot(xlist, ylist)


plt.title('Plotting Example')
plt.xlabel('Distance / ft')
plt.ylabel('Height / ft')

plt.grid(True)
# __________________________________________________________________
my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.geometry('1000x820+50+50')
my_w.title('data view on tk graph')

wrapper1 = tk.LabelFrame(my_w)
wrapper2 = tk.LabelFrame(my_w)
wrapper1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=5, pady=5)
wrapper2.pack(fill="both", padx=5, pady=5)
# __________________________________________________________________


plot1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, wrapper1)

plot1.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=5, pady=5)

ctrl_frame = tk.Frame(wrapper2, bg='green', height=100)
ctrl_frame.pack(fill="both")

tk.Button(ctrl_frame, text='View', width=15, command=lambda: None).place(relx=0.9, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.E)

my_w.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what you changed. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.

Comment: My question was how to set my graph to tkinter window.

Comment: Are you saying this isn't an answer to the question? I don't understand. The answer section is for answers only.